# Symfony - ChoiceType with multiple and resetViewTransformers returns invalid_message

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

We have upgraded our project to Symfony 4.4.35 2 months ago and now I noticed a strange behavior. When I use ChoiceType with the following configuration, the form returns error (This value is not valid):

```php
$builder->add('items', ChoiceType::class, [
    'required' => FALSE,
    'multiple' => TRUE,
]);
$builder->get('items')->resetViewTransformers();
```

The POST:

```json
form[items][0]: "val1"
form[items][1]: "val2"
```

Can someone tell me what has changed? I have tried to inspect ChoiceType.php, and find out the [problem is here](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/4.4/Extension/Core/Type/ChoiceType.php#L186):

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use (&$unknownValues, $messageTemplate) {
    if (\count($unknownValues) > 0) {
        // here is append error to form
    }
});
```

The question is: How to create multiselect with variable length and custom values?

Comment: How are valid values configured for this field ?

Comment: There is an object containing (private $items) property with getter/setter. No special validation... Object is mentioned in config option 'data_class'.

Comment: You are talking about the mapped data. My question was about the form field: what are the valid values and how are they configured in the form ? As you found in the source code: `// Throw exception if unknown values were submitted` (line 174)

Comment: As you can see, there is called resetViewTransformers (values can be various). In my case, it is an array of strings. User can add any number of strings to multiselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType` with option `allow_add`.

```php
$builder->add('items', CollectionType::class, [
    'allow_add' => TRUE,
]);
```